# delete button is not working (problem with queryselector i think?)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to programming, as you can probably tell. I'm trying to write a code for the trash button (image) that will remove the "row username" and "row expDate" elements with the same index class as the trash button. However, for some reason, it doesn't work and gives the error in the image that I uploaded below the page. I would appreciate it if you could help me identify the problem with the code. Thanks in advance!

the error in the console :
[image: error]

```js
const addbtn = document.querySelector(".newuser");
const addUserInp = document.querySelector(".addUser");
const expDate = document.querySelector(".expDate");
const userName = document.querySelector(".username");
const trash = document.querySelector(".trash");
const submitbtn = document.querySelector(".submit");
const uninp = document.querySelector(".uninp");
const edinp = document.querySelector(".edinp");
const userNameInput = document.querySelector(".usernamekey.adduserinp");
const expDateInput = document.querySelector(".expdatekey.adduserinp");
const rowz = document.querySelector(".rows");


submitbtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const unl = document.querySelectorAll(".row.username").length;
  const edl = document.querySelectorAll(".row.expDate").length;
  let un = userNameInput.value;
  let ed = expDateInput.value;
  rowz.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforebegin",
    `<h2 class="usernum">User ${unl + 1} </h2>
     <div class="row username ${unl + 1}">
       <p class=""><img src="profile-user.png" alt=""> 
       <img class="verticalline" src="icons8-vertical-line-100.png" alt="">${un}</p>
     </div>
     <div class="row expDate ${edl + 1}">
       <p class="">
         <img src="icons8-date.gif" alt=""> 
         <img class= "verticalline" src= "icons8-vertical-line-100.png" alt="">${ed}
       </p>
     </div>
     <img src="icons8-edit-30.png" alt="" class="edit ${unl + 1}">
     <img src="trash.png" alt="" class="trash ${unl + 1}">`
  );

  document.querySelectorAll(".trash").forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
      const indexClass = button.classList[1];
      console.log("Index class:", indexClass);
      document.querySelector(".row.username." + indexClass).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="lists">
    <p class="sectionTitle">Users List</p>
    <div class="rows">
      <img class="newuser" src="icons8-add-user-64.png" alt="">
      <img class="save" src="icons8-save-96.png" alt="">
      <div class=" addUser hidden ">
        <div class="uninp">
          <input class="usernamekey adduserinp " type="text" placeholder="User Name">
        </div>
        <div class="edinp">
          <input class="expdatekey adduserinp " type="date" placeholder="Expiry Date">
        </div>
        <button class="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="UserList.js"></script>
```

Comment: Class names cannot start with numbers, so `.2` is an invalid (part of your) selector and will throw an error. Change it so `user-2` or something and it will work.

Comment: I made you a snippet. It was missing a lot of `</div>`s

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very clear. The selector is invalid. `they cannot start with a digit, or a hyphen followed by a digit`

[Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

You do not event need a selector here if you  delegate, and the event handler will work for all new buttons too.

I strongly suggest you move the h2 inside the row div so you do not need to separately remove that too (but you can if you insist)

```js
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("button.trash");
  if (tgt) tgt.closest("div.row").remove();
});
```

Comment: What? Very opinionated but it does not really solve the query selector issue?

Comment: @somethinghere Ok, added why it did not work, but it is not even needed when delegating and navigating using closest

Comment: Yeah, okay, fine enough. It's just very opinionated - your approach is valid, but turns the whole thing around a bit even though the other approach was fine too.

Comment: I agree. It is one of my strongest opinions in JS when more than one event handler is needed. In this case it is almost mandatory - not only do we need to delete the parent div, but it is inserted after load.